# I want to find the $\cos ({\hat{BCD}})$. However, I don't have any idea about how to. Can you assist?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

[image]

I want to find the $\cos({\hat{BCD}})$. However, I don't have any idea about how to. Can you assist?

I'm too grateful.

Comment: Not clear whether if is a  (right) trapezium.

Comment: is this a right angle in $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$AC=\sqrt{13+12}=5,$$ which gives $$\measuredangle ACD=90^{\circ}.$$
Id est, $$\cos\measuredangle BCD=\cos\left(90^{\circ}+\arcsin\frac{2\sqrt3}{5}\right)=-\frac{2\sqrt3}{5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$AC^2 = (2\sqrt 3)^2 + (\sqrt 13)^2 = 25\\
AC = 5$

$5-12-13$ is a Pythagorean triple.
ACD is a right triangle.

$\cos \angle BCD = \cos (\angle BCA + 90^\circ) = -\sin \angle BCA$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If the angle in $B$ is a right angle, begin with computing the  length $AC$, next $\cos\measuredangle BCA$ and  $\sin\measuredangle BCA$, then determine $\cos\measuredangle ACD$ with *Al Kashi's theorem* and finally use addition formula for cosine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find $\angle BCA = \tan^{-1}(2\sqrt{3}/\sqrt{13})$.

You can find the length $AC$ as the hypotenuse of right triangle $ABC$.

Then, you can find $\angle ACD$ from the law of cosines.

Finally, $\angle BCD = \angle BCA + \angle ACD$.